# Conditions for FMCW signal reconstruction using Hilbert Transform

Tags: hilbert-transform, radar

I have an In-phase signal collected by an FMCW radar. I am trying to reconstruct the analytical signal by applying the Hilbert Transform to the In-phase signal.

Are there certain conditions that need to be satisfied in order to correctly, reconstruct the analytical signal using Hilbert Transform ? If yes, could you list them down or point to resources that are related to radar imaging?

I want to understand if there are any hidden assumptions involved when just applying Hilbert Transform to an In-phase signal to retrieve the analytical signal. For example, does the reconstruction only work for certain frequencies?

Comment: If by "reconstruction" you mean simply obtaining the analytic signal from a real-valued signal, a consideration is [boundary effects](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76792/50076). For interpreting the results, [relevant article](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83299/50076).